# Should fastfood tag be fast-food

Tags: discussion, support, tags

When doing my edit on [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/356/effect-of-eating-mcdonalds-and-other-fast-food) I changed the tag fastfood to fast-food. The next person to edit it changed it back to fastfood. Considering fastfood is an incorrect spelling shouldn't it be fast food.

I'm asking here to get a consensus and avoid an edit war on this poor persons question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Fast Food" is two words, so it is correct and more readable to include the hyphen in this case. I changed it back.